# Yum Hangs on “Setting up Update Process”

Tags: centos, yum, centos6.5

When running the following command, yum hangs on Setting up Update Process,and then server down and should to reboot from panel.
centos 6.5
/etc/yum.conf

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=16&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release

#  This is the default, if you make this bigger yum won't see if the metadata
# is newer on the remote and so you'll "gain" the bandwidth of not having to
# download the new metadata and "pay" for it by yum not having correct
# information.
#  It is esp. important, to have correct metadata, for distributions like
# Fedora which don't keep old packages around. If you don't like this checking
# interupting your command line usage, it's much better to have something
# manually check the metadata once an hour (yum-updatesd will do this).
# metadata_expire=90m

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
exclude=apache* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* da_* *ftp* exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot*
```

use strace yum update

```
pread(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0008\22\0\0007\22\0\0009\22\0\0\1\0\346\17\0\7code ("..., 4096, 19103744) = 4096
pread(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0009\22\0\0008\22\0\0:\22\0\0\1\0\346\17\0\7ext (S"..., 4096, 19107840) = 4096
pread(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0:\22\0\0009\22\0\0;\22\0\0\1\0\346\17\0\7ppropr"..., 4096, 19111936) = 4096
pread(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0;\22\0\0:\22\0\0<\22\0\0\1\0\346\17\0\7of zer"..., 4096, 19116032) = 4096
pread(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0<\22\0\0;\22\0\0=\22\0\0\1\0\346\17\0\7rlie) "..., 4096, 19120128) = 4096
pread(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0=\22\0\0<\22\0\0>\22\0\0\1\0\346\17\0\7]\n- [n"..., 4096, 19124224) = 4096
pread(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0>\22\0\0=\22\0\0?\22\0\0\1\0\346\17\0\7move g"..., 4096, 19128320) = 4096
pread(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0?\22\0\0>\22\0\0@\22\0\0\1\0\346\17\0\7param "..., 4096, 19132416) = 4096
pread(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0@\22\0\0?\22\0\0A\22\0\0\1\0\346\17\0\7dd FCo"..., 4096, 19136512) = 4096
pread(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0A\22\0\0@\22\0\0B\22\0\0\1\0\346\17\0\7driver"..., 4096, 19140608) = 4096
pread(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096, 19144704) = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
lseek(10, 19144704, SEEK_SET)           = 19144704
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
read(10, 0x7f857fd20c50, 4096)          = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
...
```

what is the problem ?!

Comment: Tell us all about your VPS.

Comment: that's dedicated server. what you need about that?

Comment: @MichaelHampton i add strace yum update results

Comment: I/O Error. Appears to be a disk problem. Can you post the output of df -h and try looking for any I/O errors in /var/log/messages.

Comment: `[root@server ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2        5.4T  135G  5.0T   3% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1      1008M   76M  881M   8% /boot
/dev/md0         40G  240M   38G   1% /tmp
` that's output of df -h and errors are `Apr 14 04:22:53 server kernel: ipmi_si: Trying default-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x0, irq 0
Apr 14 04:22:53 server kernel: ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
`

Answer (score 0):

I believe quite possibly you have an NFS mount that is not responding. I've had that same problem when one of my NFS mounts doesn't respond. Run:

```
$ sudo mount
```

and see if it hangs. If that's the case you might have to stop the problem nfs client process (kill the process). Try to see which process maybe causing the issue.

```
$ sudo lsof | grep nfs # or something that might yield nfs client file descriptors and their PIDs
```

Then exclude the problem entry from your `/etc/fstab`. Worst case you maybe need to do trial and search with the entries in `/etc/fstab`

My two cents.